# Uglify-JS Error: Unexpected character '' when concatenating then minifying select2

Tags: javascript, uglifyjs

I am concatenting [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/) to my other javascript files like so:

```
cat scripts/jquery-timeago.js scripts/jquery-autosize.js scripts/select2.js > public/vendors.js
uglifyjs -nc -o public/vendors.min.js public/vendors.js
```

However, I found an issue where there would be an empty whitespace character prepended right before `select2` only after concatenation, which then causes a parsing error in UglifyJS. If I go to the beginning of where `select2` starts in the concatenated file and press backspace, an empty character is deleted and minification works fine.

What is going on? How can I fix this?

Comment: Try starting your own scripts with a semi-colon so that any trailing lines left by previous scripts when you concatenate them are terminated properly. That could be causing a problem in your instance?

Comment: none of these scripts are "my scripts"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just opened [issue #306](https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/issues/306) on this at select2 github repo.

`select2.js` is saved with [UTF8 with BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Byte_order_mark) encoding. When `select2.js` is concatenated with other files and passed to `uglifyjs`, `uglifyjs` breaks when it comes to BOM bytes.

To fix this simply save file in UTF8 encoding (without BOM).

Comment: This also saved me when I had the same problem with SP-Services.

Comment: Thanks this saved me too! Had no idea this was the cause of the issue

Answer (score 1):

I see that this has been marked as answered. I found another way, though.

I needed to send uglify two options: ascii_only and quote_keys. Set both to true. That also works